# Não consigo acessar os dados usando a API fetch

Tags: javascript, promises, fetch

Tenho uma URL que retorna dados em JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 21,
    "solicitante": "Joao",
    "chamado": "coisa aqui no lab"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "solicitante": "Maria",
    "chamado": "projetor deu pau"
  }
]
```

Em outra página, no mesmo domínio, tento usar a API `fetch` para requisitar os dados:

```
fetch("http://" + window.location.host + "/list/", {method: 'GET'})
.then(function(res){
    console.log(res.json())
    res.map(function(item){
        console.log(item)
    });
});
```

No entanto, o `console.log(res.json())` imprime o seguinte:

> ```
> Promise {<resolved>: Array(2)}
>  __proto__: Promise
>  [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
>  [[PromiseValue]]: Array(2)
>    0: {id: 21, solicitante: "Joao", chamado: "coisa aqui no lab"}
>    1: {id: 22, solicitante: "Maria", chamado: "projetor deu pau"}
>   length: 2
>    __proto__: Array(0)
> ```

E quando tento usar o `Array.prototype.map`, recebo este erro:

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res.map is not a function
>     at <anonymous>:4:6
> ```

Como desmontado acima, não estou conseguindo acessar os dados da resposta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu problema é que [`Body.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) retorna uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), mas você não está aguardando a sua resolução para usá-lo. Isso faz com que você imprima no console a `Promise` em si, e não o seu valor resolvido.

Tal como `fetch`, `Body.json` também retorna uma `Promise`. Desse modo, você precisa aguardar a resolução das duas *promises* para usar os dados em si. Abaixo deixo um exemplo que acessa a API do GitHub:

```js
const GITHUB_API = 'https://api.github.com/users'
const GITHUB_USERNAME = 'lffg'

fetch(`${GITHUB_API}/${GITHUB_USERNAME}`)
  .then((body) => body.json()) // Note aqui que `Body.json` também retorna uma Promise.
  .then((data) => {
    // Aqui já temos as duas promesas resolvidas.
    // Você pode usar os dados como desejar. :)
 
    console.log(`O usuário ${data.login} tem ${data.public_repos} repositórios.`)
  })
```

Note que você também pode usar o `async / await` se preferir:

```js
const GITHUB_API = 'https://api.github.com/users'
const GITHUB_USERNAME = 'lffg'

async function main() {
  // O "await" espera a resolução da Promise:
  const body = await fetch(`${GITHUB_API}/${GITHUB_USERNAME}`)
  // Assim como o `fetch`, também temos que esperar a 
  // resolução da Promise. Por isso, usamos o "await":
  const data = await body.json()
  
  console.log(`O usuário ${data.login} tem ${data.public_repos} repositórios.`)
}

main()
```

#### Referência:

- [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) *(é sensato dominar esse assunto, já que  a API `fetch` é baseada em Promises)*;
- [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API);
- [`Body.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json);
- [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).